# Best practice for switching back and forth between two android activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-management

I'm trying to find out the best practice for switching between two android activities.  Several questions on SO mention this, but none seem to go into the memory or speed implications of different methods.  So far, I've come across these methods(using activity names a and b for clarity):

1. In activity a, when the user needs to move to activity b, create a new Intent pointing to activity b, and vice versa.

2.Use startActivityForResult in activity a, pointing to activity b, which then returns a result when finished.

3.Using the Intent flag ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when returning from activity b to activity a, using a new Intent pointing to activity a.

Can anyone clarify the memory and speed implications of the methods outlined above/any other methods that they know of, and suggest the best method to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. In activity a, when the user needs to move to activity b, create a new Intent pointing to activity b, and vice versa.**

You will create several instances of the activity that will be added to the backstack. So depending on the nature of your app, I recommend you not to do this. Instead you can use fragments and switch between the with the .replace method of the fragmentmanager keeping both instances of the fragments in variables in the activity.

**2.Use startActivityForResult in activity a, pointing to activity b, which then returns a result when finished.**

If you are expecting just your activity B to perform something and send something back to the activity A, then you can do this and you'll always have 1 instance of each, this is a good approach.

**3.Using the Intent flag ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when returning from activity b to activity a, using a new Intent pointing to activity a.**

This would be a good fix for your 1st solution.

Nowadays the best way to handle this is with fragments and it's what I use the most.

If you still choose to work with Activities you can set the following tags in the manifest file.

```
android:launchMode=["singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
```

Both of them work the same way having only one per instance, and this way you don't have to set the flags in the intents.

Hope it helps!